# RPM package to allow different sets of files to be installed

Tags: linux, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I would like to build an RPM that allows the installer to select which components of the software are installed.

More specifically we have 5 EAR files that are in the RPM I would like to let the installer specify an option when installing to select which EAR to install or to install all.

Is this possible with RPM?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope. There should be *no* user interaction upon RPM installation, **ever**.

You would have to make each its own `rpm`. You can have an empty `rpm` that `Requires` all of them to make a bundle, or you could make them a `yum` group.